# Error while executing a shell command using backtick in ruby

Tags: ruby, backticks

I am executing a command to find out number of files in a folder recursively. There are other processes which keep putting files in to this folder.

Example command:

```
ls -1 -rt /dump > /segmentizer.out  2> /segmentizer.err
```

Sometimes it is returning error ( ArgumentError ) and the program just hangs at that point. Here is the error

```
negative string size (or size too big)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'
```

Thank you
Ananthram

Comment: `ls` is for human-readable output. `find` is for recursively searching a directory and performing actions on the files. I suspect you don't need Ruby at all (if you construct the right `find` command), but if you insist on using it, there's the `find` stdlib for easily doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of the use cases you're trying to solve? If you just want to know the number of files in a directory and subdirectories, you can use something like:

```
Dir["/dump/**/*"].size
```